# delete html, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

have a look at this example [link text](http://elijahmanor.com/demos/jqueryuidialogiframe/index.html)
It creates a dialog with a iframe init that loads an external page.
The dialog is added to the DOM. Is it possible to delete it on dialog close event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`close` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close) of the dialog you can [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it, for example:

```
$('<iframe src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
  //...current options...
  close: function() {
    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
  }
});
```

This removes the `<iframe>` and it's contents as well as destroying the actual dialog widget around it which is no longer useful.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if i understand you corectly you can remove() iframe from the DOM

put with code in the close event

```
$("#divContainerWithiFrame").remove("iframe");
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: if I remove a html element, all childs will be removed too?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD - Yes, though there's a *much* cheaper/cleaner way to remove the specific iframe of the dialog in question, see the `close` event in my answer :)